# select "Cancel" button by default of bootstrap confirm-box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap confirm-box whose "OK" button is selected by default, I want to select "Cancel" button by default, so that accidently if user presses enter then records will be safe and will not be deleted.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a HTML tab index to the button to make it the focus.

```
<button tabindex="1">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend the answer just a bit. @Will is absolutely right about this, but for those who want to know a little more about `tabindex` attribute.

Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5

In HTML5, the tabindex attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).

In HTML 4.01, the tabindex attribute can be used with: `<a>`, `<area>`, `<button>`, `<input>`, `<object>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`.

### [You can test this here and read more about it.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_tabindex)